# How to write few lines code on top of all jsp pages in ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have a jsp project in eclipse with over 200 pages. i have to implement few session related and other jsp parameters in all the pages.

i have to write few lines of jsp code example:

```
<% if(request.getSession().getAttribute("username")==null)
   response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); %>
```

i have about 200 pages.

how to write the above code in all the pages.?

Comment: Seem you want to do this for security purpose. But writing same code in 200 jsp page will be worst thing. You should introduce filter. So that you will get your desire output with only one class.

Comment: pls advise on the filter also\

Comment: You cannot learn `filter` in a minute. Please take time and learn how filter work. You can watch youtube tutorial.

Comment: You could also add it using a JSP fragment as a prelude using the jsp-config section of a web.xml.

Comment: Add your code in a single jsp file and include that file to all other jsp. It is better go for `filter` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Implement filter in servlets

```
/**
 * @author Sumesh
 * 
 * This class will handle all the incoming request to server
 * thus it will handle authentication & session timeout
 * 
 *
 */
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            //System.out.print("Within AuthenticationFilter ... " + httpRequest.getHeader("sessionId"));
            //System.out.print("\nSession id AuthenticationFilter ... " + httpRequest.getSession().getId());
            String uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
            boolean isRest=!uri.contains("servlet");
            boolean isLogin=uri.contains("login");
            if(isRest || isLogin ){
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }else{
                if (httpRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !httpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                    // The session has been expired (or a hacker supplied a fake cookie).
                    System.out.println("Session expired");
                    String json="{\"errorCode\":\"107\"}";
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("errorCode", "107");
                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                    httpResponse.setContentType("application/json");
                    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    httpResponse.setHeader("X-JSON", json);
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    out.print(obj);
                    out.flush();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Session exists");
                    HttpSession session=httpRequest.getSession(false);
                    if(session!=null){
                        SSWSessionInfo sessionData = (SSWSessionInfo) session.getAttribute("sessionInfo"); // Object stored in session
                        if(sessionData!=null){
                            System.out.println("Logged in user :: "+sessionData.getUserID());
                            chain.doFilter(request, response);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Session expired");
                            String json="{\"errorCode\":\"107\"}";
                            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                            httpResponse.setContentType("application/json");
                            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                            httpResponse.setHeader("X-JSON", json);
                            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                            out.print(json);
                            out.flush();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("IOException raised in AuthenticationFilter");
        } catch (ServletException se) {
            System.out.println("ServletException raised in AuthenticationFilter");
        }
    }

    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return this.filterConfig;
    }

    public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
    }
}
```

Then you must add filter mapping in **web.xml**

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>authfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>authfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here i am using session timeout response as json. If you want page redirection do it there.